# dbt in Cloud Composer: general approach

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, dbt

My team currently evaluate migrating from dbt Cloud to Google Cloud Composer. I have some (not much) experience with workflow orchestration from my previous project, where we would run Spark Jobs via Argo, but I am unsure if a similar approach works with dbt (or is recommended). What I would like to know is:

- is it a valid/common approach to create a Docker Image from our dbt project in Github and refer to this Image in the DAGs.
- I figure that with this approach, I also need to install/setup dbt Core within the Docker Container, correct?
- is this way over-engineered and are there more common/leaner ways to run dbt in Cloud Composer?

Thanks a lot in advance for any hint!

Comment: https://medium.com/@ivan_toriya/step-by-step-guide-to-run-dbt-in-production-with-google-cloud-platform-fb1f035f3c7b
This may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you also need to install/setup dbt Core within the Docker Container per this [doc](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/core/docker-install).The same also says "Using a prebuilt Docker image to install dbt Core in production has a few benefits: it already includes dbt-core, one or more database adapters, and pinned versions of all their dependencies."